# R regmatches() and stringr str_extract() dragging whitespaces along

Tags: regex, r

Here's the thing:

```
test=" 2 15  3 23 12  0  0.18"
#I want to extract the 1st number separately
pattern="^ *(\\d+) +"

d=regmatches(test,gregexpr(pattern,test))
> d
[[1]]
[1] " 2 "

library(stringr)
f=str_extract(test,pattern)
> f
[1] " 2 "
```

They both bring whitespaces to the result despite usage of ()-brackets. Why? The brackets are for specifying which part of the matched pattern you want, am I wrong? I know I can trim them with `trimws()` or coerce them directly to numeric, but I wonder if I misunderstand some mechanics of patterns.

Comment: Perhaps, you need `str_match_all`.

Comment: If you use `f=str_match(test,pattern)`, `f[[2]]` will contain `2`

Comment: @stribizhev Yeah, it works, thank you. So `str_extract()` and `regmatches()` just don't support capture groups?

Comment: Looks like that. It is written in the stringr help: *`str_extract` to extract the complete match*. Also, [`regmatches`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regmatches.html) does not seem to allow digging into submatches.

Comment: @stribizhev actually `regmatches` does allow to deal with submatches if you use `regexec` instead of `gregexpr`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Using `str_match` (or `str_match_all`)

Since you want to extract a *capture group*, you can use `str_match` (or `str_match_all`). `str_extract` only extracts *whole matches*.

From [R `stringr` help](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/stringr.pdf):

> `str_match` **Extract matched groups from a string.**

and

> `str_extract` to extract **the complete match**

R code:

```
library(stringr)
test=" 2 15  3 23 12  0  0.18"
pattern="^ *(\\d+) +"
f=str_match(test,pattern)
f[[2]]
## [1] "2"
```

The `f[[2]]` will output the 2nd item that is the first capture group value.

## Using `regmatches`

As it is mentioned in the [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34807871/r-regmatches-and-stringr-str-extract-dragging-whitespaces-along?noredirect=1#comment57360046_34807871), it is also possible with `regmatches` and `regexec`:

```
test=" 2 15  3 23 12  0  0.18"
pattern="^ *(\\d+) +"
res <- regmatches(test,regexec(pattern,test))
res[[1]][2] // The res list contains all matches and submatches
## [1] "2"  // We get the item[2] from the first match to get "2"
```

See [`regexec` help page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) that says:

> `regexec` returns a list of the same length as text each element of which is either `-1` if there is no match, or a sequence of integers with the starting positions of the match **and all substrings corresponding to parenthesized subexpressions of pattern**, with attribute "match.length" a vector giving the lengths of the matches (or `-1` for no match).

## OP task specific solution

Actually, since you only are interested in 1 integer number in the beginning of a string, you could achieve what you want with a mere `gsub`:

```
> gsub("^ *(\\d+) +.*", "\\1", test)
[1] "2"
```

Comment: Since you are using `^` (thus anchoring the pattern), you will get 1 match even if you use `str_match_all`, so I have used `str_match` in the answer.