# R str_match() does what regmatches() don't

Tags: regex, r

Continuing figuring out the regex tools behavior from previous question

[R regmatches() and stringr str_extract() dragging whitespaces along](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34807871/r-regmatches-and-stringr-str-extract-dragging-whitespaces-along)

When I changed the pattern to extract to extract both the first number and the date-time

```
pattern="^ *(\\d+) +(\\d+ +\\d+ +\\d+ +\\d+ +\\d+ +[\\.\\d]+) +"
test=" 2 15  3 23 12  0  0.18 "
```

the `str_match()` gave the desired results:

```
f=str_match(test,pattern)
>f
     [,1]                       [,2] [,3]                  
[1,] " 2 15  3 23 12  0  0.18 " "2"  "15  3 23 12  0  0.18"
```

while `regmatches` didn't find the match at all

```
d=regmatches(test,gregexpr(pattern,test))
> d
[[1]]
character(0)
```

`gregexpr` output is

```
 > gregexpr(pattern[2],test[1])
[[1]]
[1] -1
attr(,"match.length")
[1] -1
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

And I don't get why it happens. Substituting `gregexp` with `regexec` and `regexpr` gives the same result.

Comment: `regmatches(test, gregexpr(pattern,test, perl = TRUE))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that you need to pass a POSIX 1003.2 extended regular expression to the `regexec` function:

```
pattern="^ *([[:digit:]]+) +([[:digit:]]+ +[[:digit:]]+ +[[:digit:]]+ +[[:digit:]]+ +[[:digit:]]+ +[.[:digit:]]+) +"
```

or

```
pattern="^ *(\\d+) +(\\d+ +\\d+ +\\d+ +\\d+ +\\d+ +[.0-9]+) +"
```

Or a shortened version with a limiting quantifier and grouping:

```
pattern="^ *(\\d+) +((?:\\d+ +){5}[.0-9]+) +"
```

The problem arises because of using an escaped `.` and a shorthand class `\d` inside a character class. That is only possible in a Perl-style (PCRE) regex. **`regexec` [does not support](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) `perl=T` option:**

> Each of these functions (***apart from `regexec`, which currently does not support Perl-style regular expressions***) operates in one of three modes

```
> test=" 2 15  3 23 12  0  0.18 "
> pattern="^ *(\\d+) +(\\d+ +\\d+ +\\d+ +\\d+ +\\d+ +[.0-9]+) +"
> regmatches(test,regexec(pattern,test))
[[1]]
[1] " 2 15  3 23 12  0  0.18 " "2"                       
[3] "15  3 23 12  0  0.18"
```

FYI, [`gregexpr`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) (that allows `perl=T` option) does not return the indices of the submatches, so it cannot be used here instead of `regexec`.